# How do I draw Microsoft style architecture images?

Tags: architecture, drawing

What software can I use to create architecture drawings like those in the Microsoft Patterns and Practices Application Architecture Guide?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Visio? I believe Visio has support for this. Also, Visual Studio 2010 has the new "Architecture" feature which supports better class, dependency, layer and other diagrams right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user68137's quick response I found the following:

[visio drawings from app architecture](http://apparch.codeplex.com/releases/view/20083)